# Azure Cache doesn't work (ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>). SDK 2.2

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

I'm trying to use Azure In-Role cache (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-in-role-cache/). I'm using dedicated role scenario (host cache in dedicated role). I have 2 roles in solution - worker role and caching role (called CacheWorkerRole).
In my worker role's app.config (cache client) I have the following:

```
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="CacheWorkerRole" />
  <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

When I do local deploy I always have error:

```
> ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure.
> Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
> unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
> on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
> Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
> account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
> through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
> server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
> sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying
> to communicate with the server: net.tcp://CacheWorkerRole:24233.
```

I just have no idea what to do next, how to solve that problem. I was trying different configurations, co-located and dedicated roles, nothing works. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Guys? No one can help with this annoying error?

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working fine with SDK 2.1 and Windows Azure Cache 2.1. Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @KevinUK check my answer below. I found no way to make it work.

Comment: I just upgraded to MVC 5.1.0 and Razor 3.1.0 etc. and caching works again now...

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was solved in the following way: instead of using in-role cache (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-in-role-cache/) I used cache service (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cache/?fb=ru-ru) which is a little different (and paid separately) but at least is works. I found no way to make in-role cache work.